# Htaccess issue with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress installed in a subfolder called blog/
I have two htaccess files, one in the root directory, one in blog folder, generated by wordpress.

The first htaccess in root directory:

```
# BEGIN
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog/.*)$

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 "/old_page" "http://example.com/new-page"
...
<IfModule>
# END
```

The second htaccess in blog folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
<IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My issue is when I navigate to http://example.com/blog/, I'm redirected to a link like that:
http://example.com/index.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlindex.htmlblog/

Comment: The root `.htaccess` file you've posted is incomplete and does not make sense as written. Please include the complete file. You should also explain what you want these directives to do - what your goal is. (However, there is nothing here that would result in the redirect you are seeing.)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your Htaccess code used for the subfolder URL, it will work fine and I have modified the root directory Htaccess code for redirection.

Please try to below code for this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

SubFolder Htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why have you limited the rewrite in the first rule to the root/homepage only? (Why introduce a hostname check?) The OP appears to be requesting `http://example.com/blog/` directly (ie. `/blog` is in the visible URL), so is this even necessary? (Except that the redirect in the root does not include `/blog`.) However, the code in the question is incomplete and the OP has not actually stated what they are trying to do, so this is going to be a guess at best. What about the old to new `Redirect` directive(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for the old URL to new URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>         
     RewriteEngine On     
     RedirectMatch 301 /old-page/ /new-page/
<IfModule>
```